# Why does scrolling a listview increase memory usage a lot?

Tags: android, listview, memory

I have a listview which contains maybe 15 rows. Each row (list item) contains 2 textfields.

When I first create the listview there is almost no memory usage, but at the moment I touch it to scroll, memory usage is increased by ~2 MB.

This tends to make GC run which makes scrolling very choppy.

I'm reusing the views, so this can not be it. Any ideas?

Comment: My guess is, it is because of scrollview caches the items you already viewed (because of which you don't need to get them again on your next visit). Not sure there is anyway to control this.

Comment: You should post your Adapter code. Maybe there's something off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the drawingCache enabled (it is by default) then each child view will be rendered into a bitmap during scrolling. This will increase memory usage but shouldn't be related to the choppiness you experience.
Are you doing any extra steps (like allocating bitmaps) in your bindView/getView method?

Comment: This is indeed the reason. The reason this resulted in choppiness was because the app was close to the heap limit and had to do alot of GC'ing. Note however that this is only on the emulator, not tested on a real device yet.

I'm guessing that turning cache off could mean trading memory use for CPU cycles, but would cache'ing really make sense when only text is used in the ListView?

Comment: I think that simply blasting a bitmap onto a surface is always going to be faster than rendering a View even if it is only a simple TextView. I think that if you render a TextView the system still needs to put as many pixels onto the surface as when it copies a bitmap to that surface. Additionally you have the overhead of the textviews render logic and the rasterizing of the text. To sum it up. I think that the memory overhead is well worth it and i never experienced problems with it on any real device.